Bounding absolute value of centered row sum of adjacency of Erdos-Renyi graph
I am trying to understand the formula (5.14) in this paper, explicitly, the goal is to upper bound $$\sum_{i\neq j}|a_{ij}-p|$$
where \begin{equation}
    a_{ij}=\begin{cases}
      1,\text{ with probability } p\\
       0,\text{ with probability } 1-p\\
    \end{cases}\,.
\end{equation}
and it is proceeded as follows:
$$\sum_{i\neq j}|a_{ij}-p|\leq \sum_{i\neq j}(a_{ij}+p)\leq n\|A\|+n^2p$$
I understand the first inequality that they use triangle inequality $|a_{ij}-p|\leq |a_{ij}|+|p|$ given $a_{ij}$ and $p$ are non-negative, although I was unsure whether this step is loosing too much.
On the second inequality, I understand that $\sum_{i\neq j}p=(n^2-n)p\leq n^2p$, but why $\sum_{i\neq j}a_{ij}\leq n\|A\|$ and why we use $\|A\|$ to bound it? Note that $\|A\|$ denotes the operator norm of $A$.
Could we just prove the random variable $\sum|a_{ij}-p|$ concentrates to its mean, by certain concentration inequality, for example Bernstein inequality?

What is $|A|$ ? And hwy you use lowercase $a$ in the first formula and uppercase in the second?

@leonbloy $|A|$ is the operator norm of $A$. I will make it consistent in my post.

Is the $A$ symmetric? Because it seems like the $a_{i,j}$ are entries of an adjacency matrix of an undirected graph.

@Keen-ameteur Yes, it is diagonal-free, symmetric

Unless I'm mistaken, the inequation has no relation with probabilities, you could omit that and write instead $a_{i,j} \in {0,1}$
